# Hide Navigation Bar and Tool Bar Safari Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have this code:

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.canAnimateBars)
        [self animeteBars:scrollView];
}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if(self.canAnimateBars)
        [self animeteBars:scrollView];
}

-(void)animeteBars:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    bool hide = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY);

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    if (hide)
        self.quickLinkToolBarBotom.constant = -44.0;
    else
        self.quickLinkToolBarBotom.constant = 0.0;

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate Methods

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.canAnimateBars = YES;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

It is working ok, but Would like to archive the same behaviour of the Safari animation.

I have tried this library AMScrollingNavbar but I can't make it work with the Tool Bar.

How can I make the calculations to move the bars while I'm scrolling the Web view like in Safari.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. i think this code used for you.

```
-(void)animeteBars:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    bool hide = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY);

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat duration = 0.3;

    if (hide)
    {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
          self.quickLinkToolBarBotom.constant = -44.0;
        } completion:nil];

    }
    else
    {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
          self.quickLinkToolBarBotom.constant = 0.0;
        } completion:nil];
    }
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:hide animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that does not archive the same behaviour as Safari does, your code does the same as mine